# handling WSA_IO_PENDING for socket ::send

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock2

[`result = ::send(s, buf, length, flag)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send)

How much data will be eventually sent? when I get `result == SOCKET_ERROR` and `WSAGetLastError () == WSA_IO_PENDING` 
will `length` bytes of `buf` be all eventually sent?

or I need to try re-sending the same buf data again?

On the other hand

> WSA_IO_PENDING
>
> Overlapped operations will complete later.
>
> The application has initiated an overlapped operation that cannot be completed immediately. A completion indication will be given later
>   when the operation has been completed....

it sounds to me like the send operation WILL be completed later....

> UPDATE: the further question is asked here
>   [Unexpected WSA_IO_PENDING from blocking (overlapped I/O) Winsock2 calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419993/unexpected-wsa-io-pending-from-blocking-overlapped-i-o-winsock2-calls)

Comment: You should use `WSAGetLastError` instead of `getLastError`

Comment: corrected. thanks. was typo... in code it is indeed WSAGetLastError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation page that you've linked:

> If no error occurs, send returns the total number of bytes sent, which can be less than the number requested to be sent in the len parameter. Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned

That is if `result == SOCKET_ERROR` then nothing was sent.

As for `WSA_IO_PENDING`, it could occur if you were using async io, for example [`WSASend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasend). In this case amount of bytes actually sent needs to be retrieved later, possibly using io completion routine.

Comment: thanks.  the document of WSA_IO_PENDING just makes me a little bit confused

Comment: @rnd_nr_gen Note that `WSA_IO_PENDING` is not even listed among possible error codes for this function. It may occur if you were using async io rather than blocking `send` call. That is `send` does not perform overlapped operations.

Comment: the same goes to `::recv`. I do get WSA_IO_PENDING from ::recv even the error code is also not listed.  (Win 10)

Comment: @rnd_nr_gen as VTT said, `send()` and `recv()` DO NOT perform overlapped I/O, so it is simply not possible for them to report `WSA_IO_PENDING`. If you put the socket into non-blocking mode, `send()`/`recv()` can report `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, otherwise they operate in synchronous mode instead. Only overlapped I/O enabled functions, like `WSASend/Ex()`, `WSARecv()`, `RIOSend/Ex()`, etc can report `WSA_IO_PENDING`.

Comment: then it would be really interesting why I **did** get WSA_IO_PENDING from, at least. ::recv() 

All I have used for the socket are

#include <WS2tcpip.h>, ws2_32.lib, ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP), ::WSAIoctl(s, _WSAIOW(IOC_VENDOR, 4), &heartbeat, sizeof(heartbeat), 0, 0, &no, 0, 0) for keep-alive. and ::send(), ::recv()

on MSVS2015/Win10

Comment: @rnd_nr_gen Maybe you've got It from `WSAIoctl`?

Comment: not from WSAIoctl. indeed from ::recv(). randomly but not unusual. from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket  the ::scoket has overlapped attribute as a default.

Answer (score 0):

after some research and experiment..
here are some facts.

[::socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) will have implicitly overlapped attribute enabled.

A socket can be created w/o overlapped attribute `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`  via [::WSASocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasocketa) or via [setsocketopt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-setsockopt) / [SO_OPENTYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/sol-socket-socket-options), however timeout feature (e.g. `SO_RCVTIMEO`) requires overlapped attribute.

When using [::send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send) [::recv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv) a WSA_IO_PENDING error is possible and should be handled with [WSAGetOverlappedResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsagetoverlappedresult) (I observed such behavior since Windows 10)

Alternatively, to use ::WSARecv or ::WSASend instead.

There are still questions unanwsered:

> UPDATE: the further question is asked here
>   [Unexpected WSA_IO_PENDING from blocking (overlapped I/O) Winsock2 calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419993/unexpected-wsa-io-pending-from-blocking-overlapped-i-o-winsock2-calls)

Comment: you can not use `WSAGetOverlappedResult` after `send` or `recv` by very simply reason - this api not take pointer to `WSAOVERLAPPED`. so which `WSAOVERLAPPED` you will be use in call `WSAGetOverlappedResult` ?

Comment: That is more and less my initial question and guessed assumption. The ´send´ and ´recv´ blocking call can have overlapped I/O by default. The same as if you call  ´WSASend´ and ´WSARecv´ with both NULL lpOverlapped and NULL lpCompletionRoutine as stated from MSDN.  And after those calls you may get SOCKET_ERROR with WSA_IO_PENDING. It is very strange to me that a blocking call has such error. Should I just ignore the "error", OR handle it by closing socket??  ´WSAGetOverlappedResult´ can be called with WSAOVERLAPPED having NULL event handle. Can I use it to poll result?

Comment: I mean  ´WSAGetOverlappedResult´ with an empty WSAOVERLAPPED object.
I hope the Win API will handle it properly for such situation, however I did not find any confident reference...   Any comment?

Comment: *I mean `WSAGetOverlappedResult` with an empty `WSAOVERLAPPED` object* - no. this is always error and senseless. in `´WSAGetOverlappedResult` need use exactly pointer to overlapped used in io request

Comment: *I hope the Win API will handle it properly for such situation* - impossible. the pointer to overlapped is main parameter for `[WSA]GetOverlappedResult` - without it impossible determinate - are io is finished, if finished - with which error code, if no error - how many bytes transferred. all this information stored in `WSAOVERLAPPED` object. no valid object - nothing will be

Comment: *It is very strange to me that a blocking call has such error.* - here agree. the `send` or `recv` must never return `WSA_IO_PENDING`. very strange if you got it (and not mistake)

Comment: probably I should post another question about it.  It is really strange... to get WSA_IS_PENDING from very basic send and recv calls.

Comment: dont know how this can happens - are you sure that functions fails or you get last error exactly from this api calls ?

Comment: yes. it is also single thread....  ,however, within a software which has other tons of network related library running in other threads.. I assume they should not interfere with each other

Comment: UPDATE: the question is re-asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419993/unexpected-wsa-io-pending-from-blocking-overlapped-i-o-winsock2-calls